# Red lightning bolt icon over player icon

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

In my HotS party, a player had a red lightning bolt icon over their player icon in the upper-right corner while we were waiting for a game. I know that a lightning bolt means connectivity issues in Overwatch, but this is different (on the hero select screen). What does this red lightning bolt mean?

[image: Red lightning bolt]

Comment: The only thing I was able to find that mentions this red lightning bolt you talk about is [this post](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/heroes/topic/16953975896) which didn't seem to get much attention. I'm going to bet it just means that players connection is poor.

Comment: Maybe it signals that the player left a game early or he has some sort of penalty like he cant write in chat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The red lightning means that the player has disconnected from the game. It's the same icon as you would see in a channel list.

[image: Picture of chatbox notification when someone disconnects]

And here's the chatbox notification, "player_name has disconnected from the party", which shows that the player has disconnected.

[image: Zoomed in]

Zoomed-in version.